# Python code isn't returning anything

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this code in Pycharm but whenever I try to run the code I don't have any output to my shell.

```
import bs4
import requests

url = "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=python&l=Chicago%2C+IL, https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=java&l=Chicago%2C+IL, https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=javascript&l=Chicago%2C+IL, https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=c%23&l=Chicago%2C+IL, https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=php&l=Chicago%2C+IL, https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=c%2B%2B&l=Chicago%2C+IL, https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=sql&l=Chicago%2C+IL, https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=ruby&l=Chicago%2C+IL, https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=perl&l=Chicago%2C+IL, https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=visual+basic&l=Chicago%2C+IL, https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=.net&l=Chicago%2C+IL, https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=python&l=Chicago%2C+IL, https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=r&l=Chicago%2C+IL, https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=swift&l=Chicago%2C+IL"

urls = [url]
visited = [url]

while len(urls) >0:
    try:
        htmltext = requests.get(urls[0])
    except:
        print (urls[0])
    tags = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmltext.content, 'lxml')
    urls.pop(0)
    for tag in tags.select('#searchCount'):
        tag = (str(tag[0].getText()))
        print (tag)
```

Comment: No input, or no output?

Comment: Your ``url`` is actually a list of URLs; you need to split it up into individual items.  As it is, you're trying to load the whole thing as a single URL, which of course fails.

Comment: 1st: your `try` isn't indented correctly; 2nd: your url is a list of urls as @jasonharper mentioned; 3rd: you keep getting the first url with `urls[0]`; 4th: what is your output supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what exactly you want as your output.
But I have tried to correct your code

```
import bs4
import requests

url = //your urls

urls = url.split(","); //to make urls a list of urls and not a list that only has one element

while len(urls) > 0:

    try:
        htmltext = requests.get(urls[0])
    except:
        print (urls[0])
    tags = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmltext.content, 'lxml')
    for tag in tags.select('#searchCount'):
        print "inside search of " + str(urls.pop(0))
        try:
            tag = (str(tag.getText()))
            print (tag)
        except:
            print "exception in search"
```